# Django Haystack: responsibilities of the template and model indexes

Tags: django, django-templates, django-haystack

I've gone over the docs, and I've even created a few search back ends, but I"m still really confused on what these things do in haystack.  Is the search back end searching the fields you  put in your class that inherits indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable, or is the back end searching the text inside your template?  Can someone explain  this to me?

In django haystack you will create a class that defines what fields should be queried (well that's how I understand it) like so:

```
class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title', boost=1.75)
    description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='description')
    short_description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='short_description')

    def get_model(self):
        return Product

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(active=True,
                                           published_at__lte=datetime.now())
```

You'll also create a template txt that will do something - I"m not sure what. I know that the search backend will go over this template during the searching algorithm.

```
{{ object.name }}
{{ object.description }}
{{ object.short_description }}
{% for related in object.related %}
    {{ related.name }}
    {{ related.description }}
{% endfor %}

{% for category in object.categories.all %}
    {% if category.active %}
        {{ category.name }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see the template has some fields that my index class doesn't have, however, these will be searched by the search backend. So why even have fields in the index? What are the rolls of the index class, and the index template? Can someone please explain this to me.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand you. Can you add some example (preferably in code) of such a backend, and explain in detail what exactly is confusing you? Are you asking how does Haystack work in the background, are you generally confused about how to use some feature?

Comment: I did as best I could yuvi. I'm just really confused on what exactly is the purpose on the rolls of the index class and the index template, and what's being searched by the backend.

Comment: That's a lot clearer. I'm not sure I can help you, but now the question's a lot better. Hopefully, some haystack ninja will come along soon!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ProductIndex` class is the main thing here. Haystack will use this configuration to index your `Product` model according to the fields you have chosen to be indexed and in what way. You can read more about it [here](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-searchindexes).

The template which you have created will be used by this field `text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)`. In this template we include every important data from model or related models, why? because this is used to perform search query on all data if you don't want to lookup in just one field.

```
# filtering on single field
qs = SearchQuerySet().models(Product).filter(name=query)

# filtering on multiple fields
qs = SearchQuerySet().models(Product).filter(name=query).filter(description=query)

# filtering on all data where ever there is a match
qs = SearchQuerySet().models(Product).filter(text=query)
```